# Csh script call C program,arguments issue

Tags: c, linux

This the line from the csh script

```
./model2grd $model -D$nx/$ny/$nz -O$x0/$y0 -I$dx/$dy -L$layer -C$coverage -Avel.dat -Gvel.grd
```

This is part of the model2grd.c

```
for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
    if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
        switch (argv[i][1]) {
            case 'G':
                grdfile = &argv[i][2];
                lgrd = TRUE;
                break;
            case 'C':
                cov = &argv[i][2];
                lcov = TRUE;
                break;
            case 'A':
                xyzfile = &argv[i][2];
                lxyz = TRUE;
                break;
            case 'D':
                sscanf(&argv[i][2],"%d/%d/%d",&nx,&ny,&nz);
                break;
            case 'I':
                sscanf(&argv[i][2], "%lf/%lf", &dx, &dy);
                break;
            case 'O':
                sscanf(&argv[i][2], "%lf/%lf", &xmin, &ymin);
                break;
            case 'L':
                layer = atoi(&argv[i][2]);
                break;
            case 'N':
                nan = (float)atof(&argv[i][2]);
                break;
            case 'Z':
                cvalue = (float)atof(&argv[i][2]);
                break;
            case 'V':
                verbose = TRUE;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Does this mean that it takes with D(nx,ny,nz),with O(xmin and ymin),with L layer and with C coverage?Are Avel.dat and Gvel.grd input files or not?

Comment: Compile your C code with all warnings & debugging info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) & **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Or use `getopt` to do the dirty work for you: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html

Comment: Wouldn't that be **your** task to tell what the semantics are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Avel.dat` and `Gvel.grd` are not input files.  Look at the argument parsing again.

```
 switch (argv[i][1]) {
        case 'G':
            grdfile = &argv[i][2];
            lgrd = TRUE;
            break;
```

Consider that with this argument:

> -Gvel.grd

In plain English, the `switch` examines the *second* character of each argument.  In this case `-Gvel.grd` is the argument, so it looks at the `G`.  Passing that test, the case statement then derives the address of the character that comes *immediately after* the `G` within the character string.  In other words, the `v`.

Therefore, the file name is actually `vel.grd`.  You should be able to apply this same logic to the rest of the arguments that follow the same pattern.